# Missing custom constructor in Java class

Tags: java

There is this question on LeetCode that asks you to flatten a multilevel doubly LinkedList. I got stuck in it, so I started googling around. I found a Java solution for it but it doesn’t make sense.

the given `Node` class doesn’t have any constructor (custom) but in the solution, they are making an object of it, like if it has a custom constructor!

like the following:

```
class Node {
    public int val;
    public Node prev;
    public Node next;
    public Node child;
};
```

```
Node dummy = new Node(0, null, head, null);
```

how is that possible? it’s like if the `Node` class has some sort of a hidden constructor!

Comment: have you actually tried to compile that?

Comment: Maybe they are using some code generation library like Lombok with `@AllArgsConstructor`?

Comment: Well it's simple - it's not possible. They may assume you know how to make appropriate constructor and they omitted it for brevity, maybe they have some code-gen library and you omitted some code here, or they have a mistake. As is this does not compile, there's no magic.

Comment: @Stultuske, yes, i tried to compile it (with four different Java versions), none of them work, IntelliJ keeps throwing me an error “make a custom constructor”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do hidden constructor, specially at compilation.

But, there is few solutions :

- Use compilation library such as lombok (with `@AllArgsConstructor` such as Ogod mentionned)
- Use gradle plugin
- Create your own constructor like :

```java
public Node(int val, Node prev, Node next, Node child) {
   this.val = val;
   this.prev = prev;
   this.next = next;
   this.child = child;
}
```

- IDE like Intellij allow you to automatically generate constructor

Comment: Just read about `lombok`, apparently (as it seems) LeetCode is using it. the Annotation that @Ogod mentioned suits the situation.